# Impact of the WSOLA analysis increment on the time stretching factor

Tags: sola

WSOLA, basically, is the same as OLA but with a dynamic hop size. That part is clear to me. What is not so clear is the following: The stretching factor is determined by alpha = Hs / Ha and WSOLA uses a small increment, obtained through cross-correlation, to determine where the next input frame will be extracted. If that's the case, doesn't that small increment introduce a deviation between the requested alpha and the real one? After all, that increment determines a new analysis hop size, Ha' = Ha + incr, meaning that, if we maintain the same synthesis hop size, the alpha will change.

Comment: like you, i assume a constant synthesis hop size (usually 1/2 the window length, using a complementary window like the Hann window).  but if you're doing some kind of autocorrelation on the input, you want the input window (and by that, i don't mean the analysis window) to hop from a portion of the waveform to another place in the waveform that is similar.  i.e. if your autocorrelation tells you the period is $P$ samples, you want the distance between the latter half of the previous window to the earlier half of the new window, you want that distance to be $P$ samples so the waveforms line up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there can be jitter between the requested alpha and the one provided by WSOLA; but that jitter will average out over the long run, and the peak jitter is bounded by on the order of twice the lowest frequency (half the longest period) accepted by the autocorrelation algorithm.

Comment: *"...(half the longest period) accepted by the autocorrelation algorithm."* so this is the magnitude, in time offset either side of a fixed delay, as the definition of the bound or maximum of the jitter, do i have that correctly?